# Edit one field across multiple nodes

Tags: entities

Is there a way to edit a single field (for example: publication date) across a few dozen nodes?

I added a field called "Publication date" to an existing content type, and now I need to add a date to a whole lot of them. I'd love to have a table display showing the node title, and the field in question next to it in an editable column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Build a view that shows the nodes you want, then add the display style to be "views bulk operations", adding the option to update a field. Then, when you view this view, you'll see a table of all of the items you want along with checkboxes and a dropdown to mass-update the fields of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

The editable fields module (http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) works well with views.  So you could build a view with node title and this pub date field making the pub date editable.

Comment: P.S. I was assuming that each node required a different date based on your question.  If they all require the same date, use Charlie's solution.