# How to implement a multi-node edit workflow?

Tags: nodes, forms

I'm not sure if this exists. I'm looking for a multi-node edit workflow. I want to select multiple nodes then for each node selected show an edit form. This would be something like showing the first node edit form, then on save, show the next edit form, etc.

I came across the [Multi Node Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/multi_node_edit) module, but it looks to be dead.

There's also this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51657/edit-one-field-across-multiple-nodes) but it's not exactly what I want. [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) seems to work only for multiple edits on the same field, not one after another node edit forms.

Comment: You can do it with Rules: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules or a custom module :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something similar with a combination of [editable fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) and views.

Then by loading all the nodes in a view with a table format, you can use the editable field and edit it right on the spot with AJAX.
[Updating multiple nodes in a view using editablefields](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/12/13/drupal-7-update-multiple-nodes-at-once-in-a-views/)

[image]

If you wanted to update multiple nodes at once (assuming fields are the same) you can use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

The exact functionality you are asking for is defiantly custom and will require your own module. Selecting the nodes you want then editing them one after another is highly inconvenient IMO. A report/table format is much better for working with data.